# Telling git not to change a file

Tags: git

We have a Drupal website that we maintain in a git repo. Because the site is a public site but is for a private audience, we want to set the `robots.txt` to disallow all.

However, Drupal makes core updates from time to time, and these contain a `robots.txt` in the root of the site repo, amongst many other files. The core update is provided through a `tar.gz` file, not through a remote of another repo. Updates to Drupal core, then, show up as diffs, just as if you had edited the code yourself.

If someone updates Drupal core in our repo, they might overwrite our custom `robots.txt`, and we probably would not notice until results started showing up in Google again.

Is there a way to "fix" or pin the state of a file in a git repo? Or at least make it noisy to someone who goes to commit changes to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4710353/985949

Comment: The accepted answer in the marked duplicate suggests using `--assume-unchanged`, but what you probably want is `--skip-worktree` which is intended for this kind of situations.

Comment: @1615903 still a little confused, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/151841 says "is useful when you instruct git not to touch a specific file ever because developers should change it." But developers shouldn't change it (they will likely do so accidentally, unpacking Drupal core)-- unless they are specifically intending to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered renaming the *other* rpbots.txt to a different name on your branch? That way if the robots.txt file changes on the other branch and you merge, the changes would land on the renamed file and not *your* robots.txt

Comment: ...?  But if the file is renamed to something other than ROBOTS.TXT then it won't do what ROBOTS.TXT does...

Comment: Then I'm not following. You want to get changes from another branch but _not_ the changes they do on robots.txt and you want _your_ robots.txt to remain the same no matter what they do on the other branch? Or you just want to get a conflict and resolve it if they change the upstream robots.txt? Cause if that's the case, then that's the way git works "out of the box".

Comment: you might want to pay attention to usernames, because I'm not the one who asked the question.  I'm just pointing out that what you recommend *won't do what OP said was desired*.

Comment: hahaha :-D ok. Let's see what the feedback is. Thanks for taking the time to read, just in case.

Comment: Hrm.  Well, I just reread what you're suggesting and I withdraw my original objection, replacing it with these two instead:  (1) It puts *way* too much trust in git's rename detection; (2) as OP indicates that the updates are manually applied from a .tgz, it wouldn't work.

Comment: About (2), there's no problem with that. I would keep upstream code "as is" on a separate branch so that I can then merge them on my own downstream branch. About (1), _perhaps_. I've tried with other situations like this (not too complex) and it works fine but you are right in terms of it _relying_ on git's rename detection.

Comment: Well, committing through a branch would at least help (though it isn't apparently OP's current workflow, so you might want to add that to your answer).  I guess on the other point, I'll just leave it that it puts more trust in rename detection that would make *me* comfortable.

Comment: I've been spending a little bit of brainpower on this problem. i think the best thing they could do is manage upstream changes "as is" on their own branch and merge from there. That way whenever they merge from upstream they would get a conflict on robots.txt and they would be able to set it to _their_ version disregarding changes from upstream.

Comment: This solution won't work in this. The repository is a Drupal site installation. Regularly there will be updates from Drupal, to the core. This occasionally includes `robots.txt`. I am probably not going to be able to convince the Drupal Organzation to change the name of the stock `robots.txt` in whats intended to be a web root directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to reflect new info about how updates are received:

You could use a hook.  Since you want this to be globally enforced you'd probably want to use a server-side `pre-receive` hook to reject any push that modifies `robots.txt`.  (You could use client-side `pre-commit` hooks to catch it earlier, but this would have to be set up correctly for each clone of the repo so isn't as good a guarantee.)

As to how exactly to write the hook, I'd start by looking at the examples in .git/hooks ; I think the `pre-commit` hook shows how to do a content-based reject.

Comment: You wouldn't see a merge conflict, because the Drupal core updates are from a tar.gz, not a repo.