# Checkout error with working tree clean

Tags: git

Please, 
I get the error "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout" but my working tree is clean.

does anyone have any idea of what is going on here?

```
$ git status
On branch experiment
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git checkout develop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
app/build.gradle
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

(the file `app/build.gradle` is not in my `.gitignore` file)

---

This is the top level .gitignore file:

```
### Android ###

# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# Intellij
.idea
*.iml

# Keystore files
*.jks

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and     later
.externalNativeBuild

# Mac
.DS_Store

### Android Patch ###
gen-external-apklibs
```

---

This is a .gitignore file inside the /app directory (I don't know why it is there):

```
build

# Secrets
secrets.properties
```

Comment: Maybe you're ignoring all gradle files and not specific one? Please post the `.gitignore` content.

Comment: What the output of `git status`?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim OP already posted it.

Comment: My bad. This is really weird though. Are there any patterns in your `.gitignore` file that match the `build.gradle` one? Perhaps the whole directory? What do you get when you try a `git clean -n`?

Comment: what is the output of `git status  --untracked-files=all` ?

Comment: (you can also add `--ignore`to get *sure* that `app/build.gradle` is not in `.gitignore`)

Comment: Is `app/build.gradle` listed in the output of `git clean -nxfd`? careful with the command, although `-n` should be a dry run of the clean command it's always worth exercising caution =D

Comment: @Pac0 thank you pac, that command returns nothing

Comment: @Chris the output is Would remove .gradle/
Would remove .idea/
Would remove app/app.iml
Would remove app/build/
Would remove build/
Would remove local.properties

Comment: @Chris Don’t mix `-f` and `-n` there o.O You’re lucky `-n` has a higher precedence.

Comment: @LisaAnne Can you try a `git add -f app/build.gradle` and then check the status again? Does it still not appear in there?

Comment: `.gitignore` isn't the only file that could be defining a relevant ignore rule.  Is there anything in `.git/info/exclude`?  If you run `git config --list |grep core.excludesFile` does it show anything? (If so, that config value names another file that might include ignore rules.)

Comment: @poke That's better advice, for some reason I picked up the bad habit of using both at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wild shot :

I once read about a hidden "assume unchanged flag" (see [this answer for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30402432/86072)),
and the only way I know of for seeing if this flag is active on a file is (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363197/can-i-get-a-list-of-files-marked-assume-unchanged)) :

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[[:lower:]]'
```

What do you see when you run the above command on your repo ?

Comment: Wow, indeed it was that, you are a genius!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else wonders what's the next step after you notice that a file was added to assume unchanged with `git ls-files -v | grep '^[[:lower:]]'`, you need to remove the flag with this command:

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged PATH/TO/THE/FILE.wtf`

After that you can either `git commit` or `git stash` the changes and then you'll be able to `git checkout`

Answer (score -2):

do a git status
see the files that are still to be added or changed.

This comes when there are local cahnges that can be overwritten

If you see that you dont need local changes

use git stash to flush local changes and try again

Comment: He has already showed the output of git status, which says there is nothing to do.