# Checkout error with working tree clean, no-assume-updates not working, force checkout not working

Tags: git

So this seems basically to be the same problem here [Checkout error with working tree clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052237/checkout-error-with-working-tree-clean) only none of the solutions work.

Here is my terminal output

```
username folder % git status
On branch feature/branchname
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/branchname'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
username folder % git checkout staging
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    apps/content/package.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
username folder % git update-index --no-assume-unchanged apps/content/package.json
username folder % git checkout staging                                            
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    apps/content/package.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
username folder % git checkout -f staging                                         
error: Entry 'apps/content/package.json' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
username folder % git stash
No local changes to save
username folder % git checkout staging   
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    apps/content/package.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

So I do status, working tree clean, I do checkout get message file needs to be committed or stashed, I stash, checkout again same message (I have also tried committing without success) and so forth.

Comment: If you are confident that have no changes you could try `git reset --hard HEAD && git checkout staging`?

Comment: git reset hard reset things told me my working tree was clean again, checkout staging told me I still needed to change that file.

Comment: Do you have a second worktree somewhere else?

Comment: not that I know of.

Comment: I was thinking could try - delete content folder, checkout staging, stash. Brutal will let me continue working but no actual knowledge what caused situation.

Comment: `git diff -w` does this output anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git restore --staged apps/content/package.json
git restore apps/content/package.json
git reset --hard
git checkout staging
```